# Delete contents of a string including and after a specific word

Tags: c#, substring

I need to take a string, and then delete its contents including and after the specified phrase, and then return the last word left over. 
In this case, "more information".

Basically, this script should take the string

```
     "Please visit 

this 
website
 for more information if you have questions"
```

And return the word `"for"`

(Note this is just an example, the string could be anything and I made it messed up with line breaks intentionally because that's how it looks half the time.)

The split method below works, returning the last word, but the substring method does not work.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
   public static string InfoParse(string input)


{
    string extract = input;


    extract =  input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf("more information"));


    extract = extract.Split(' ').Last();

    return extract;



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this:

```
    public static string InfoParse(string input)
    {
        //string extract = input;
        string extract = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf("more information"));
        extract = extract.Split(new string[] {" ", "\r\n", "\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last();
        return extract;
    }
```

or this to show what was wrong with your code:

```
public static string InfoParse(string input)
{
    //string extract = input;
    string extract = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(" more information"));
    extract = extract.Split(' ').Last();
    return extract;
}
```

Your split returned the entry **after** the last space and the last space was exactly the space before "more information" --> So it returns an empty string

EDIT: Now also with linebreak

Comment: the first one is clearly more robust (considering their "messed up with line breaks etc.") better not count on consistent whitespace either.

Comment: That's right, just wanted to show the exact problem of original Question-Source

Comment: It works, but it's considering line breaks as part of the last word. Is there a way to have it treat a linebreak the same as a space for purposes of parsing the last word?

Comment: I've edit my answer, just use the first Method, should also work for linebreaks now

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegularExpression:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string InfoParse(string input, string word)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"\s?(?<LastBefore>\w+)\s+" + word, RegexOptions.Singleline);
    if (m.Success)
        return m.Groups["LastBefore"].Value;
    return null;
}
```